# What is this shortcut to determine primality?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

I'm watching [this](http://youtu.be/PUDQ3ypFhew?t=25m9s), he says that David Slowinski discovered the biggest prime in 1984: $2^{132,049}$-1 and that it took 1 week on a Cray supercomputer: using some shortcut and that the absence of this shortcut would make the process last the age of the universe. What's this shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers of the form $2^n-1$ can be tested by the [Lucas-Lehmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) method, which is not available for numbers not of that form.

Comment: Can you give me a brief description of this method?

Comment: I have edited in a link to the description at Wikipedia, but you could just type $$\rm Lucas\ Lehmer$$ into the internet and take your pick of places to look.

Comment: I know I can, I just thought that it would be something deadly complicated and if this was true, I'd need a simplification.

Comment: @Gustavo Take a look at it. It's not complicated at all.

Comment: Yep, I'm reading about it. Thanks for your answer.